# Pyside: setting the background of a row in a QVBoxLayout widget

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtgui, qlayout

I have a QVBoxLayout widget with a few rows, each containing several buttons. On an event, I'd like to highlight one of the rows by changing its background. I've tried many different approaches and none worked. What's a good way for achieving this?

Comment: `QVBoxLayout widget with a few rows, each containing several buttons` -> you sure not looking for QGridLayout instead? Either way, have you tried `setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");` on the corresponding widgets where you can change black to the color you wish to have?

Comment: I get this kind of error for pretty much anything I try: `AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QVBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'`

Comment: Yes because the attribute is for QWidgets. Layouts are not widgets. You will need to set in, e.g. in a loop for your pushbuttons or the container widget of them if there is any.

Comment: OK. Can you provide a simple example for me to follow?

Comment: it would be more useful if you could provide your vbox construction and then one can point it out more precisely and more usefully for the posterity. Although, I am not a python guru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following on the widget(s) in the desired row replacing black with the color you wish to have:

```
myWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
```